# Round Robin using Queue

Tags: python, cpu, round-robin

My function Round Robin takes 2 parameters; the first is the list of Processes inputted and the time quantum. It Should use a queue or Priority Queue, which is a requirement.

I have a problem with the outputs of the Completion Time. It outputs incorrectly.
I also use the Class Process.

```
class Process:
    def __init__(self, process_id, arrival_time, burst_time, priority):
        self.process_id = process_id
        self.arrival_time = arrival_time
        self.burst_time = burst_time
        self.priority = priority
        self.completion_time = 0
        self.waiting_time = 0
        self.turnaround_time = 0
        self.remaining_time = burst_time

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.priority == other.priority:
            if self.arrival_time == other.arrival_time:
                return self.process_id < other.process_id
            return self.arrival_time < other.arrival_time
        if self.priority < other.priority:
            return self.priority < other.priority
        if self.burst_time == other.burst_time:
            return self.process_id < other.process_id
        if self.arrival_time == 0 and other.arrival_time != 0:
            return True
        elif self.arrival_time != 0 and other.arrival_time == 0:
            return False
        elif self.arrival_time == other.arrival_time:
            return self.burst_time < other.burst_time
        return self.burst_time < other.burst_time
```

I use the __lt __ for other OS Scheduling Function such as Preemptive Priority and SJF.

and Here is my Round Robin Function.

```
def round_robin(processes, time_quantum):
    rr = Queue()

    for process in processes:
        rr.put(process)

    waiting_time = [0] * len(processes)
    turn_around_time = [0] * len(processes)
    curr_time = 0

    while not rr.empty():
        process = rr.get()
        if process.remaining_time <= time_quantum:
            curr_time += process.remaining_time
            process.completion_time = curr_time
            process.remaining_time = 0
        else:
            curr_time += time_quantum
            process.remaining_time -= time_quantum
            rr.put(process)

        if process.remaining_time > 0:
            rr.put(process)

    for i in range(len(processes)):
        turn_around_time[i] = processes[i].completion_time - processes[i].arrival_time
        processes[i].waiting_time = turn_around_time[i] - processes[i].burst_time
        processes[i].turnaround_time = turn_around_time[i]

    return processes
```

This uses a queue and when the time remaining is not zero it will put it back to the queue. But the problem is that the sequence it computes.
For Example:
my inputs are:

```
processes = [
        Process(1, 0, 24, 4),
        Process(2, 0, 3, 3),
        Process(3, 0, 3, 2)
    ]

    time_quantum = 2
```

This inputs gives an incorrect output which is:

```
Process 1 Completion Time: 30
Process 2 Completion Time: 11
Process 3 Completion Time: 12
```

When it is supposed to be:

```
Process 1 Completion Time: 30
Process 2 Completion Time: 9
Process 3 Completion Time: 10
```

Please help me correct my code!

I tried another method for Round Robin.

```
def round_robin(processes: List[Process], time_quantum: int) -> List[Process]:
    queue = Queue()
    total_time = 0
    total_time_counted = 0
    wait_time = 0
    turnaround_time = 0
    completed_processes = []

    for process in processes:
        total_time += process.burst_time
        queue.put(process)

    while not queue.empty():
        current_process = queue.get()

        if current_process.remaining_time <= time_quantum:
            total_time_counted += current_process.remaining_time
            total_time -= current_process.remaining_time
            current_process.completion_time = total_time_counted
            current_process.turnaround_time = total_time_counted - current_process.arrival_time
            current_process.waiting_time = current_process.turnaround_time - current_process.burst_time
            completed_processes.append(current_process)
            current_process.remaining_time = 0
        else:
            total_time_counted += time_quantum
            total_time -= time_quantum
            current_process.remaining_time -= time_quantum
            queue.put(current_process)

    return completed_processes
```

This now uses a List. It takes the List of the Processes done. Although with the given input above.

my inputs are:

```
processes = [
        Process(1, 0, 24, 4),
        Process(2, 0, 3, 3),
        Process(3, 0, 3, 2)
    ]

    time_quantum = 2
```

It gives a correct answer:

```
Process 1 Completion Time: 30
Process 2 Completion Time: 9
Process 3 Completion Time: 10
```

but if I try other inputs such as:

```
processes = [
        Process(1, 0, 7, 4),
        Process(2, 2, 4, 3),
        Process(3, 4, 1, 2),
        Process(3, 5, 4, 1)
    ]

    time_quantum = 2
```

It gives an incorrect answer:

```
Process 1 Completion Time: 16
Process 2 Completion Time: 11
Process 3 Completion Time: 5
Process 4 Completion Time: 13
```

When the outputs should be:

```
Process 1 Completion Time: 16
Process 2 Completion Time: 9
Process 3 Completion Time: 7
Process 4 Completion Time: 15
```

Comment: If `__lt__` is not relevant, it can be omitted for clarity. But it's also hard to guess what you want the code to do it's not clear why the results are not correct. Maybe edit the question to explain the algorithm you want to implement?

Comment: @JohnBayko The Round Robin is a CPU Scheduling Algorithm that takes a list of processes and then enqueue it with their arrival time. The process must be in a ready state (where the arrival time is less than or equal to the current time of the run time) in order to enqueue it. Then the duration of each process in the queue is based on the Time Quantum then it will dequeue the current process if there's new Process (if the arrival time of the other process is less than the current time) if not then it will continue to use that process. This will happen until all the process burst time is used.

Comment: In your first implementation of `round_robin`, `rr.put(process)` is done twice in the case where the process has not completed.

Comment: The second implementation doesn't take account of process arrival time, i.e. it doesn't enforce that *"the process must be in a ready state (where the arrival time is less than or equal to the current time of the run time) in order to enqueue it."*

Comment: There are several round robin algorithms, they have different rules and results. I was wondering which you are trying to implement. For example, how is priority treated? Should there be aging? Is running time a factor? It looks like you're using a standard FIFO `Queue` class, and just running processes in order they're listed, is that your intent?